# Reset $PATH Variable to Default Kali setting

Tags: bash, terminal, kali-linux, path, bashrc

Running Kali Linux Rolling Distro.

Attempted to install Cuda Toolkit to the /opt/ directory using the following syntax:

```
chmod +x cudatoolkit_4.1.28_linux_64_ubuntu11.04.run
./cudatoolkit_4.1.28_linux_64_ubuntu11.04.runConfigure  

echo PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin >> ~/.bashrc
echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib >> ~/.bashrc
echo export PATH >> ~/.bashrc
echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now every time I open my terminal I see this at the very top:

> bash: /opt/cuda/bin: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /opt/cuda/bin: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: No such file or directory
>
> bash: /usr/local/sbin: Is a directory

```
root@kali:~# cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar
# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi    
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: /opt/cuda/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/cuda/lib
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: /opt/cuda/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: /usr/local/sbin
```

I need to return to the default Kali Linux setting, in order to remove this 'bash message' I see every time I fire up the terminal.

Comment: Actually show us what is in `~/.bashrc` by running `cat ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Post has been edited

Comment: Those are all simple syntax errors in that awful script.  Open it up in your favorite text editor and fix the lines near the end starting with the `PATH`.  You'll have to actually combine those different path lines in one without any space.

Comment: What Julie is saying is: change `: /` (with a space) to `:/` (no space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fact that

```
echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib >> ~/.bashrc
```

gets expanded to

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/opt/cuda/lib
```

indicated that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is either unset or `NULL`.

try this instead

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
if [[ -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ]]
then
    echo 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cuda/lib' >> ~/.bashrc
else                                                                
    echo 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib' >> ~/.bashrc
fi
echo 'export PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Don't you want the old `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` included in the new one?

Comment: @JigglyNaga good point, I wondered if anyone would pick that up. answer updated.